# How to export c# code from Bot Framework Composer

Tags: c#, botframework

It is not clear for me  how to export c# source code from  Microsoft Bot Framework Composer .  The BOT project (sub)folder does not contain any cs file. There is only a project file( ".botproj" ).

Even if I opt to create a personalized c# runtime  ( in BOT Composer project settings )  I cant find all cs files with Bot processing in "runtime" folder.

thks,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-add-custom-action#export-runtime)?

Comment: Is Vinoth's answer acceptable?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!!

Comment: Click the check mark to accept it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot framework Composer contains only .dialog files (declarative adaptive dialogs)

Just search .dialog in the composer folder , you can find all the dialog information.

If you want export the bot project use the command export this Bot as zip

[image]